# How to open detail view in editable format as shown in admin page?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to show the user the details they entered in an editable format as we can see in

#### Edit:

Changed the code and tried to explain the question in a better way

#### view.py

```py
def change_contact(request, contact_id):
    try:
        form = AddToPhoneBookForm(instance=Contact.objects.get(pk=contact_id))
        form.instance.user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = AddToPhoneBookForm()

        context = {
            'form': form
        }

        return render(request, "CallCenter/add_to_phone_book.html", context)
```

#### forms.py

```py
class AddToPhoneBookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'phone_book']
```

This view loads the forms as I want it to but the changes made here is not reflected in the database. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need to use *get()* instead of *filter()* .Get returns the single object whereas filter will returns the queryset

```
contact = Contact.objects.get(phone_book__id=phone_book_id)
```

And in template you don't need to use forloop `{{contact.first_name}}` will give the result for you

EDIT: you will save the data with POST request so you need to handle for POST request also and there are a lots of things you need to know please read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/)

And change your view like this

```
 def change_contact(request, contact_id):
        contact = Contact.objects.get(pk=contact_id)
        form = AddToPhoneBookForm(instance=contact)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AddToPhoneBookForm(request.POST,instance=contact)        
            if form.is_valid():
               obj=form.save(commit=False)
               obj.user = request.user
               obj.save()
               return redirect('some-path')
        context = {
            'form': form,'contact':contact
        }

        return render(request, "CallCenter/add_to_phone_book.html", context)
```

Comment: The user will not be able to edit the contact even then

Comment: For this you need a form and pass the this contact in this form as an instance and save it

Comment: I use filter so that if multiple contacts are present in a single phonebook then the user will be able to  see all of those contacts

Comment: I changed the question to explain my problem in a better way. Am I missing something?